# Prevent empty lines in ejs for loops

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have the following simple ejs template:

```
<% for (var i =0; i < 10; ++i) { %>
    - <%- i %>
<% } %>
```

This renders the following:

```
- 0

- 1

- 2

- 3

- 4

- 5

- 6

- 7

- 8

- 9
```

How can I prevent ejs to create empty lines like these?

If possible I don't want to modify the result string but to tell ejs to not render these empty lines. How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Trim-mode ('newline slurp') tag, trims following newline.

```
 <% i -%> or <% -%> or <%= i -%> or <%- i -%>
```

All you need is the hypen.

In the [Features](https://github.com/mde/ejs#features) section, there you can see this option:

> - Newline-trim mode ('newline slurping') with `-%>` ending tag

Note that the new version of `ejs` is maintained at [`mde/ejs`](https://github.com/mde/ejs) (not [`tj/ejs`](https://github.com/tj/ejs) anymore).

Answer (score 1):

If you add a '-' before the "%>", it will make line break

```
<% for (var i =0; i < 10; ++i) { %>
     - <%- i -%>
<% } %>
```

But I found it quite tricky to use, because it not always work as expected.

This [issue](https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/43) has more details on it.